# How to eliminate custom posts where the "date" value is expired?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have this code calling a list of custom post events. It calls them in the right order, but when the event is passed, it stil displays the event. Any ideas what's wrong with the code?

```
  $args2 = array(
    "post_type" => "gig",
    "meta_key" => "_gigswhen", // Change to the meta key you want to sort by
            "meta_query" => array(
            array(
             "meta_key" => "_gigswhen",
             "value" => date(),
                "compare" => ">=",
           ),
     ),
    "orderby" => "meta_value_num", // This stays as 'meta_value' or 'meta_value_num' (str sorting or numeric sorting)
    "order" => "ASC"
    );
```

The date in "_gigswhen" is stored as strtotime (unix timecode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `date()` with no parameters. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Try this for your `meta_query` argument:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => '_gigswhen',
        'value' => time()
        'compare' => '<'
    )
)
```

Comment: Not quite working.. I should have mentioned that the gig date is stored as a unix time code.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that it applies to UNIX timestamps.

Comment: for some reason, it's just showing all the gigs.. Doesn't seem to be affecting much, my way or yours.

Comment: I'm afraid it's difficult to debug based on these details. You may consider echoing `$this->request` just after line 2612 here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2612 in order to see exactly what WP is attempting to fetch.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that I wrote `meta_key` when it should be just `key` (I think I'd copied what you wrote above). I updated my answer to reflect this.